# How to update watermark realtime while streaming video with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, live, live-streaming

I'm trying to add a watermark to video while streaming. However this watermark get update every second. How to tell ffmpeg to update the watermark ? Try added -r 2 before -i watermark but didn't works.

The ffmpeg command like this

> ffmpeg -i /tmp/45893_video_0.ts -i /tmp/watermark.jpg -filter_complex '[1:v]colorkey=0x2bade0:0.3:0.2[ckout];[0:v][ckout]overlay[out]' -map '[out]' -f flv "rtmp://"

Comment: `...-f image2 -i /tmp/watermark.jpg...`

Comment: it doesn't work. I mean, while ffmpeg is streaming video, I make a change on /tmp/watermark.jpg and I hope it change on video, too. But now it didn't change. It keep the watermark like when it start

Comment: Add `-loop 1` in between

Comment: The image is not reloaded, even if you use `loop`. You have to pipe it in. What I did in a similar case was something like `-f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgba ... -i pipe:0` with a script feeding each of the overlay's frames as they changed.

Comment: Can you please send me the full ffmpeg command. And about the pipe script, you mean it read the image file and print to stdout (and ffmpeg will read it), is that right ?

Comment: @boygiandi The command is exactly like yours except you read raw image data via stdin. You can also do it with sockets. Or, if you don't need alpha like I did you could probably use `mjpeg`.

Comment: @aergistal `-f image2 -loop 1 -i image out` works here, with mid-process input update.

Comment: @Mulvya Thanks for the update, I'll try it with git HEAD